# Wordpress Admin Notices displaying wrong

Tags: admin, wordpress

I'm having problems with my admin notices, which are generated inside of a Class. For some reason it displays like so:

[image]

The notice should be beneath the title "Leads", and its like this on every page. Here is my code:

```
    public function leads_admin_notices(){
    if( ! get_option('lead_to_email') ){
        echo '<div id="message" class="error below-h2">
                <p>An email is required to send leads. <a href="'.admin_url('edit.php?post_type=leads&page=leads-settings').'">Edit Leads Settings</a>.</p>
             </div>';
    }
}
```

and I'm calling it like so:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', array($this, 'leads_admin_notices') );
```

Comment: Check your source, you are probably placing the `add_action()` call before the header. It's likely a simple job of moving it underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `below-h2` class should do the trick

Comment: This works and the solution is similar to the one in this question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220650/how-to-change-the-location-of-admin-notice-in-html-without-using-javascript/342200#342200